# React onClick event yields: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined", despite binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

I'm writing a React script that will render a bunch of `<a />` elements from a previously defined array.

```
...
render:
...
    var behaviourComponents = this.props.myObjectArray.map(function(element) {
                    return <a className="crumbFile" onClick={this._myFunction.bind(this,element.value1)}>{element.value2}</a>;
                });
    return (
...
<div>{behaviourComponents}</div>
...)
```

This works fine when there is no function call with onClick. However, when there is I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_myFunction' of undefined".

This is extra strange because I have a component right before it with an onClick function call that works fine (`<a class="btn header" style={buttonStyle} onClick={this._onLoad}>Load</a>`), which makes me think this is a scoping issue due to the map() function. However, I used .bind(), so I am not too sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the context inside of the function you pass to `map()` is not referring to your React component class.  By default, the context is the global Window object.

There are a few ways to solve this issue:

1) Bind the correct context of `this` to the function passed to `map()`.

```
this.props.myObjectArray.map(function(element) {
    ...
}.bind(this));
```

2) Pass the correct context as the second argument to `map()`

```
this.props.myObjectArray.map(function(element) {
    ...
}, this);
```

3) Use an ES6 arrow function, which will bind the correct context for you.

```
this.props.myObjectArray.map(element => {
    ...
});
```